# Windows 10 optimizations for video capture

Tags: windows, windows-10, video-capture

What specific Windows configurations can be taken to improve the quality of video capture on a Windows 10 PC? The video capture is being done via a Pinnacle AV pci card, and is capturing footage off of an old analog 8mm camcorder. The PC itself is an older Dell Optiplex 745. There are two SATA drives in the PC, both non-SSD.

I am interested specifically in Windows 10 configuration changes. I am not asking a generic "make it go faster" question, nor am I seeking downvotes or "just buy a newer PC" responses either; but am interested in what configurations will reduce latency and improve the quality of video capture.

Googling phrases such as "Windows 10 low latency" or "Windows 10 optimize for video capture" has produced nothing of value. Searching here has yielded little, but maybe nobody has asked yet.

Comment: What kind of latency or quality issue are you observing though? Can you be more specific? To be honest I don't think the OS has much to do with it. It's probably just the software/encoder from Pinnacle sucks (as always? :P)

Comment: If I record some video, at times the quality is fine. Other times, there is a lot of breakup in the audio portion of the video, with that classic "choppiness" reminiscent of the computer not being able to keep up. Gut instinct tells me some annoying app on the PC is trying to run an update and the most inappropriate time.